# how can I create a Message Box that captures user's response?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to view a message box. this should happen when the user tries to exit the program while there are child windows active. if there are no active child windows then the application should end. i have written some code but when the user clicks on NO, the message box immediately pops up again.if you have a better way of doing this please feel free to share, thank you.

```
private void MainWindow_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Form child = this.ActiveMdiChild;

        if(child != null)
        {
            DialogResult res = 
                MessageBox.Show( child.Name +
                "Do you want to exit?", "Exit",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);


            if (res == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;

                child.Focus();

            }
            else if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                Application.Exit();

            }

        }
        else if (child == null)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }   

    }
```

Comment: Not an answer but a hint: ``if(child != null) {...} else if (child == null)`` is pretty redundant...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) if there are child form who canceled closing then main form will have its `e.Cancel` already set to true. Also there's no need to call `Application.Exit()`, because after the main form closes the application should end. Try this:

```
private void MainWindow_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Form child = this.ActiveMdiChild;

    if (child != null)
    {
        DialogResult res = 
            MessageBox.Show( child.Name +
            "Do you want to exit?", "Exit",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);


        if (res == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            child.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked after i changed e.Close to e.Cancel and i also added e.Cancel = true; above child.Focus();

Comment: Yes, e.Cancel. My bad. I fixed it.

Comment: i think you have to add "e.Cancel = true;" above child.Focus(); i tried it with and without and im sure this has to be there, otherwise it wont work.

Comment: I see. Well, I never tried it, so I'll just add it there. MSDN sometimes is not to be trusted :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're handling the `FormClosing` event multiple times. Can you paste code that adds `MainWindow_FormClosing` to the event?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the call to Application.Exit(). Why do you need it if it is the Main form anyway?
You can filter this out by adding this check on the top of the function

```
if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall) return;
```

Comment: ``Application.Exit();`` should never be called if the user selects No.

Comment: @ Jacek Gorgoń Ahh you are right! My mistake! Read it fast and thought he meant when he exits was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                Application.Exit();

            }
```

just remove this from your code code